# Gravity change as a function of time only

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, earth

Is it possible to find how gravity changes with time? That is, height is not part of the equation.

For example, $g$ can be expressed as a function of height that does not involve time with this relation:

$g_i=g_0 (r /(r+h))^2$

where $g_i$ is $g$ at any height and $g_0$ is on the Earth's surface.

I also found through the above relation that $g_i = g_{i-1} ((r+h_{i-1})/(r+h_i))^2$

By the same token, there should be a relation between $g_0, g_i,   t$
that does not involve distances. An object in free fall will be going through changes in $g$ as time progresses. Is it possible to create such an expression?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it requires calculus. Are you up for it?

Comment: Yes, most definitely.

Comment: Okay, here's a hint: Consider the acceleration to be constant as the object falls over a height of dh in time dt and write the relation. Then integrate it from h = $h_0$ to h = 0

Comment: Perhaps I'm not getting it. If I integrate from $h_0$ to $0$ then I end up with an equation that has $h_0$ again. But my goal is to end up with an equation that has only $t$ and $g$ at another point in time and there is no $h$ or $h_0$ involved. It would really help if you can show what you mean.

Comment: That is not possible - because the time taken to fall down depends on the height it is released from, since its acceleration depends on the height it is at. However, that $h_0$ will be a known parameter for any application, so it doesn't count as a variable.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So going back to your proposed strategy. What if I did it the other way around? I start with dt/dh and then integrate it from t=t1 to t=0. That way I ensure to end up with time and $h_0$

Comment: You don't know what $t_1$ is before you solve the problem, do you?

Comment: Yes, I do know. And I will also know what $t_{i+1}$